# MVC passing value from button to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view

Hi i have a problem passing values from View to controller

I have a set of rendered buttons:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <form method="post">
@{ 
            var ordernumbers = Model.OrderDetail.Count();
            var buttonnumber = ordernumbers <= 1 ? 0 : (ordernumbers / 100) + 1;

            if (buttonnumber == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < buttonnumber; i++)
                {
                <input type="submit" name="button" value="@i"  class="btn btn-primary text-center" aria-pressed="true"
                        asp-action="UpdatePage"></input>
                }
            }

}
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And i need to pass the value of each button to my controller

```
    public class OrderdetailsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<OrderdetailsController> _logger;
        private readonly IOrderDetailsRepository _orderdetailsrepository;
        OrderDetailsModel orderdetails = new();

        public OrderdetailsController(ILogger<OrderdetailsController> logger,IOrderDetailsRepository orderrepository)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _orderdetailsrepository = orderrepository;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var orderDetails = _orderdetailsrepository.GetOrderDetails();
            orderdetails = new(orderDetails);
            return View(orderdetails);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UpdatePage(int button)
        {
            orderdetails.ItemsToShow = button;
            return View(orderdetails);
        }


        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
```

That should update the model and re-render the View. But it's not working as intended and i'm preety sure i did something wrong. I searched all over the place but could not find a working answer.

I have tried everything and i need to render the View again.

Comment: Can you share some more code? Show how your data model is declared and defined before passing to the view, please. BTW, the `UpdatePage(int button)` action method is using the `orderdetails` but you don't define it.

Comment: Hi , sorry i did update the whole class :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but i did find my mistake . I did forget to add the name of the View in the UpdatePage. Now it has the View("Index",Orderdetails); instead of View(Orderdetails);. After removing some bugs now it works as intended :)